# insert page break in html to syncfusion pdf report after some element

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-3.0, syncfusion, html-to-pdf

i am trying to break page after some element i am using this code

```
 <p style=\"page-break-after:always\">
```

i am using syncfusion pdf report generator

So here in the content I have several records to show in the PDF.

Now I want that these individual records are shown in the same page, meaning I do not want to show the related content to appear on two pages.

If there is not enough space on current page then whole content is transfer to next page, not split in two pages.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn on or off detection of page breaks in HTML using the AutoDetectPageBreak property.

```
using (HtmlConverter html = new HtmlConverter())
{
 // Enable auto detect page break.
 html.AutoDetectPageBreak = true;

 // Convert here
}
```

If set to false, the converter will split the pages based on the size of PdfPage.